# Ethereum testnet balance not getting updated

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, linux

I have sent 1ETH to my newly created address in testnet. 
The node chaindata is updated and syncing is done (`eth.syncing` gives `false`). Also if I do `eth.getBlock(2670189)`, I can see my TxHash in the JSON. But `eth.getBalance` on the account gives 0.

System config: Google Cloud VM with 4 vCPUs, 12 GB memory, Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

TxHash: [0x6f1262ec20c80835113d474b0c9d15c980ed61bb06440ee6960ea1d9531a3097](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x6f1262ec20c80835113d474b0c9d15c980ed61bb06440ee6960ea1d9531a3097)

Comment: Etherscan shows the account that you sent the ether to as having 2.5 ether from 3 transactions (including the one you list above).  How did you sent the ether?  From the same computer/software you are using to call `eth.getBalance`?

Comment: Are you using geth v1.8?

Comment: @Howard I made 3 transactions to that address from MetaMask, but that shouldn't be any issue as they were successful.

Comment: @Ismael yes its version 1.8.0-stable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay the balance got updated after a long period of Syncing. The thing that misguided me and probably many others who are new to Ethereum is that `eth.syncing` gives `false` but still fast syncing is not over. Until you see this line in the terminal where geth is syncing

```
INFO [02-19|09:57:59] Fast sync complete, auto disabling 
INFO [02-19|09:58:00] Finished upgrading chain index           type=bloombits
INFO [02-19|09:58:14] Imported new chain segment
```

This came way later than when `eth.syncing` was `false`

Comment: Always make sure that eth.blocknumber returns current or near to current block in fast sync.